# How to reset a singleton instance in python in this case?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a Singleton class in Python using this code:

```
class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]
    def clear(cls):
        cls._instances = {}
class MyClass(metaclass=Singleton):
    def my_attribute(*args):
        if len(args) == 1:
            MyClass.i_attribute = args[0]
        elif len(args) == 0:
            try:
                return MyClass.i_attribute
            except:
                MyClass.i_attribute = 0
```

but the clear() method does not seem to work:

```
MyClass.my_attribute(42)  
MyClass.clear()
MyClass.my_attribute()  # still returns 42, but I expect 0
```

How do I delete the instance of MyClass so that I am back to 0 instances?

Comment: You say it's not working, but how are you using it and why do you think it's not working?

Comment: You can't manually delete objects in Python. (The fact that you want to delete the instance at all suggests a singleton probably isn't a great fit for your use case, though you wouldn't be able to manually delete non-singletons either.)

Comment: You're not even storing your data on the singleton anyway, or using the singleton for anything at all. You're storing data on the class, and your `my_attribute` function doesn't even work if you try to call it through the singleton.

Comment: Perhaps you copy-pasted the code wrong? The function MyClass.my_attribute() works just fine for me in python3

Comment: Yeah, because that's not going through the singleton. You don't even create the singleton.

Comment: The metaclass you've used is designed to ensure that every time you do `MyClass()`, you get the same instance back. You never do `MyClass()` at all, though. You just have data stored on the class directly.

Comment: I can't remotely imagine what problem you hope to solve this way. It is unlikely that you have a reason to set up a Singleton in the first place. I consider the pattern highly overused, and that's taking into account that I've barely heard it mentioned in years.

Answer (score 6):

The singleton metaclass collects in the _instances attribute all the instantiated children. Therefore, if you want to clear the _instances attributes only for a specific class, you can:

1. Redefine the Singleton class, to make _instances an attribute of the class instantiated by the metaclass:

```
class Singleton(type):
    """
    Singleton metaclass, which stores a single instance of the children class in the children class itself.

    The metaclass exposes also a clearing mechanism, that clear the single instance:
    * clear: use as follows 'ClassToClear.clear()
    """

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, methods):
        cls._instance = None
        super().__init__(name, bases, methods)

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls._instance:
            return cls._instance
        cls._instance = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instance

    def clear(cls):
        cls._instance = None
```

Using this new definition of the singleton, you can write a clear method that can be called by any of the classes initialized with the Singleton metaclass and it will clear the _instance attribute.
So in your case, `MyClass.clear()` would reset the _instance attribute to None.

2. Add a clear method, which removes only the children class from the Singleton._instances dictionary:

```
class SingletonRegistry(type):
    """
    Singleton metaclass, which implements a registry of all classes that are created through this metaclass and
    the corresponding instance of that class (added at the first creation).

    The metaclass exposes also a clearing mechanism, that clears a specific class from the registry:
    * clear: use as follows 'ClassToClear.clear()
    * clear_all: use as follows 'SingletonRegistry.clear_all()
    """

    _instances = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(SingletonRegistry, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]

    def clear(cls):
        _ = cls._instances.pop(cls, None)

    def clear_all(*args, **kwargs):
        SingletonRegistry._instances = {}
```

In this case, if you would like to clear only one specific child class, then you could write `MyClass.clear()`, which will cause the MyClass key to be removed from Singleton._instances dictionary.
This structure allows also to clear all key in the _instances dictionary by writing `SingletonRegistry.clear_all()`.

Comment: Can you add a usage example of method 1?

Answer (score 0):

user2357112 is right. Here is the correct code:

```
class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]
    def clear(cls):
        cls._instances = {}
class MyClass(metaclass=Singleton):
    def my_attribute(*args):
        my = MyClass()
        if len(args) == 1:
            my.i_attribute = args[0]
        elif len(args) == 0:
            try:
                return my.i_attribute
            except:
                my.i_attribute = 0   
                return my.i_attribute
```

Comment: [Monica is someone else](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/393048/4518341). You're talking about [user2357112](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112-supports-monica), who supports Monica.

Comment: BTW could you clarify what they were right about? In other words, what did you change and why? Otherwise this answer isn't super helpful.